# How to avoid build of module dependency when not included in a specific flavor?

Tags: android, gradle

I currently have a project containing **two modules** :

- app
- stub

The app module is the main one and contains an application relying on our **customer library**. This library is not fully functional yet and so we started development with a home made **stub of this library**, contained in the stub module.

The solution we have now is to declare **two flavors** in app :

- regular (the one using the actual lib)
- stub (the one using the stub module)

Here is an extract of the app/build.gradle file :

```
android {
    ...
    productFlavors {
        regular {
            applicationId "com.example"
        }
        stub {
            applicationId "com.example.stub"
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    ...
    regularCompile ('com.customer:superhypelib:1.0.0')
    stubCompile project(':stub')
}
```

The dependency is correctly handled, each flavor relies on the correct dependency. My issue happens when I try to build regular variant, when running :

```
gradlew :app:assembleRegular
```

**This will lead to build the stub module even if there is no depencency** ! I can't understand why and for some reasons, the customer needs to avoid this.

Anyone see why this happen and, even better, how to get rid of this ?

Thanks !